# How can I sort array using comparable?

Tags: java

Consider I have this:

```
class Sort {

private Integer[] intArray = {30,20,50,100,1,2,6,1,3,5};

Sort() {

    sortObject(intArray);
}

 public <T extends Comparable<T>> void sortObject(T[] array) {

    T el = array[0];

    for(T elements : array) {
        if(el.compareTo(elements)<0) {
            /// ??????
        }        

    }
```

How can I sort my Integer array values using compareTo()?

Comment: If I do not want this. I need to use compareTo().P.s. it is not homework

Comment: Then open the `java.util.Arrays` class and copy-paste the code of the `sort(array, comparator)` method.

Comment: The question is unclear: from the question it looks like you don't know _how_ to sort an array, i.e., what sorting algorithms are. However, your question is about the comparable interface and java. Please clean up the question.

Comment: I know what are sorting algorithms, but I misunderstood the concept of compareTo().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do: `Arrays.sort(intArray).`

if you want to do reverse sort i.e. sort in descending order than do as below:

```
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o2-o1;
        }
    });
```

where `a` is  `Integer[] a = {1, 3, 2, 7, 9, 11};`

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do by hand what `Arrays.sort(Object[])` does?  Then, what you really need is a book on algorithms, and then you should look at the various implementations: bubble, insertion, quick, Shell, heap, etc.  Java has its own algorithm which it documents somewhere.

However, you should not be using generic types since you know you are using `Integer`.  You know you have `Integer`, so use it.  `Integer` implements `Comparable`, so there's no need for the extra declaration.

```
class SortExample {

    private Integer[] intArray = {30,20,50,100,1,2,6,1,3,5};

    SortExample() {
        System.out.println("Before sort " + Arrays.toString(intArray));
        sortObject(intArray);
        System.out.println("After  sort " + Arrays.toString(intArray));
    }

    public void sortObject(Integer[] array) {
        Arrays.sort(intArray);
    }

}
```

If you want to test an algorithm *you* use, replace the `sortObject` method.  For bubble sort, use this:

```
// Figure out how efficient your algorithm is.
private int numberSwaps = 0;

public void sortObject(Integer[] array) {
    final int last = array.length - 1;
    for (int end = last; end > 0; end--) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= end; i++) {
            // No need for compareTo here; it does exactly the same thing.
            if (array[i] < array[i-1]) {
                swap(array, i, i-1);
                numberSwaps++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Needed " + numberSwaps + " swaps.");
}

private void swap(Integer[] array], int from, int to) {
    int temp = array[from];
    array[from] = array[to];
    array[to] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The individual `compareTo()` method of the `Comparable` elements cannot be overriden, unless one defines a separate subclass to `Comparable` and only applies the sorting to instances of that subclass.

For a generic `Comparable` type, overriding of the `compare()` method of the `Comparator` class on every sorting, provides access to the `compareTo()` method of the array components. Here is a quick implementation using `Java` inheritance and an option to do the sorting in ascending or descending order:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ArraySorter
{
    private ArraySorter()
    {
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(
        final T[] array, final boolean ascending)
    {
        Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<T>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(T o1, T o2)
            {
                return (ascending?o1.compareTo(o2):o2.compareTo(o1));
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] intArray = {30,20,50,100,1,2,6,1,3,5};

        System.out.println("UNSORTED:   " + Arrays.asList(intArray));

        ArraySorter.sort(intArray, true);

        System.out.println("ASCENDING:  " + Arrays.asList(intArray));

        ArraySorter.sort(intArray, false);

        System.out.println("DESCENDING: " + Arrays.asList(intArray));
    }
}
```

Running the static `sort()` method above using the `intArray` value, as the `main()` method of the `ArraySorter` class does, the following output is produced:

```
UNSORTED:   [30, 20, 50, 100, 1, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5]
ASCENDING:  [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 20, 30, 50, 100]
DESCENDING: [100, 50, 30, 20, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

Of course, the above result, for ascending order, is identical to just calling `Arrays.sort(intArray)`.